# How to addClass to parent on button select

Tags: jquery

I'm really having trouble attempting to toggle classes when I select the 'Learn More' button within the card. I've tried to make it affect the parent of the button I select only, but instead all cards that share the same class are affected.

I'm not using ID's as the amount of cards generated will vary depending on another aspect.

```js
(function() {
  $(".show-more, .show-less").click(function() {
    $(".card")
      .toggleClass("card--small")
      .toggleClass("card--medium");
    $(".show-less").toggleClass("hide");
    $(".show-more").toggleClass("hide");
  });
})();
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,300);
:root {
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms;
  transition: all 300ms;
}

:root.bg--medium {
  background-color: #E53935;
}

:root.bg--small {
  background-color: #4527A0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  font-weight: 400;
}

button {
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
}

.is_current:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.is_current {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -5px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -5px, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card {
  will-change: transform;
  margin: 8px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  height: 35%;
  width: 344px;
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
}

.card:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card__image {
  position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
  transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
}

.card__image:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms;
  transition: all 500ms;
  bottom: 0;
}

.card__title {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
  transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
}

.card__subtitle {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #000;
  left: 88px;
  right: 0;
  top: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0 16px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
  transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
}

.card__text {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 100px;
  padding: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.6;
  position: absolute;
  color: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: width 200ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
  transition: width 200ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
  -webkit-transition: delay 0.1s;
  transition: delay 0.1s;
}

.card__action-bar {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0 8px;
  border-top: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  boz-sizing: border-box;
  height: 52px;
  -webkit-transition: left 200ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
  transition: left 200ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
}

.card__button {
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 52px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  color: #FF1744;
}

.card--medium {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 13px 25px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 11px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  box-shadow: 0 13px 25px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 11px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  height: 208px;
  min-height: 208px;
}

.card--medium .card__image {
  border-radius: 1px 1px 0 0;
  left: -100%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.card--medium .card__title {
  color: #FF1744;
  top: 16px;
}

.card--medium .card__text {
  font-size: 16px;
  top: 50px;
}

.card--medium .card__action-bar {
  left: 0;
}

.card--small {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  height: 136px;
  min-height: 136px;
}

.card--small .card__image {
  border-radius: 1px 0 0 1px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 88px;
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 136px;
}

.card--small .card__image:after {
  opacity: 0;
}

.card--small .card__title {
  color: #000;
  left: 88px;
  top: 8px;
}

.card--small .card__subtitle {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 88px;
}

.card--small .card__text {
  top: 30px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.card--small .card__action-bar {
  left: 88px;
}

.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Card-->

<div class="card card--small">
  <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature);"></div>
  <h2 class="card__title">Nature</h2><span class="card__subtitle">By Unknown</span>
  <p class="card__text">Located two hours south of Sydney in the Southern Highland of New South Wales...</p>
  <div class="card__action-bar">
    <button class="card__button">SHARE</button>
    <button class="card__button show-more">LEARN MORE</button>
    <button class="card__button show-less hide">SHOW LESS</button>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Card-->

<div class="card card--small">
  <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature);"></div>
  <h2 class="card__title">Nature</h2><span class="card__subtitle">By Unknown</span>
  <p class="card__text">Located two hours south of Sydney in the Southern Highland of New South Wales...</p>
  <div class="card__action-bar">
    <button class="card__button">SHARE</button>
    <button class="card__button show-more">LEARN MORE</button>
    <button class="card__button show-less hide">SHOW LESS</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try using the `closest` function. `$(this).closest(".card").toggleClass(...`

Comment: Thanks, I've not come across this selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with your selector, which is not accessing the parent of the click target at all, but is instead targeting all objects with the `.card` class. [See jQuery's `.closest()` docs](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) for more info.

```js
(function() {
  $(".show-more, .show-less").click(function(e) {
    // Get parent based on click target
    // $(this) represents the element that was clicked
    let $parent = $(this).closest(".card");
    $parent
      .toggleClass("card--small card--medium")
      .find(".show-more, .show-less").toggleClass("hide");
  });
})();
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,300);
:root {
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms;
  transition: all 300ms;
}

:root.bg--medium {
  background-color: #E53935;
}

:root.bg--small {
  background-color: #4527A0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  font-weight: 400;
}

button {
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
}

.is_current:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.is_current {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -5px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -5px, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card {
  will-change: transform;
  margin: 8px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  height: 35%;
  width: 344px;
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
}

.card:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card__image {
  position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
  transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
}

.card__image:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms;
  transition: all 500ms;
  bottom: 0;
}

.card__title {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
  transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
}

.card__subtitle {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #000;
  left: 88px;
  right: 0;
  top: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0 16px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
  transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
}

.card__text {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 100px;
  padding: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.6;
  position: absolute;
  color: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: width 200ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
  transition: width 200ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
  -webkit-transition: delay 0.1s;
  transition: delay 0.1s;
}

.card__action-bar {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0 8px;
  border-top: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  boz-sizing: border-box;
  height: 52px;
  -webkit-transition: left 200ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
  transition: left 200ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
}

.card__button {
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 52px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  color: #FF1744;
}

.card--medium {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 13px 25px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 11px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  box-shadow: 0 13px 25px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 11px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  height: 208px;
  min-height: 208px;
}

.card--medium .card__image {
  border-radius: 1px 1px 0 0;
  left: -100%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.card--medium .card__title {
  color: #FF1744;
  top: 16px;
}

.card--medium .card__text {
  font-size: 16px;
  top: 50px;
}

.card--medium .card__action-bar {
  left: 0;
}

.card--small {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  height: 136px;
  min-height: 136px;
}

.card--small .card__image {
  border-radius: 1px 0 0 1px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 88px;
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 136px;
}

.card--small .card__image:after {
  opacity: 0;
}

.card--small .card__title {
  color: #000;
  left: 88px;
  top: 8px;
}

.card--small .card__subtitle {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 88px;
}

.card--small .card__text {
  top: 30px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.card--small .card__action-bar {
  left: 88px;
}

.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Card-->

<div class="card card--small">
  <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature);"></div>
  <h2 class="card__title">Nature</h2><span class="card__subtitle">By Unknown</span>
  <p class="card__text">Located two hours south of Sydney in the Southern Highland of New South Wales...</p>
  <div class="card__action-bar">
    <button class="card__button">SHARE</button>
    <button class="card__button show-more">LEARN MORE</button>
    <button class="card__button show-less hide">SHOW LESS</button>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Card-->

<div class="card card--small">
  <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature);"></div>
  <h2 class="card__title">Nature</h2><span class="card__subtitle">By Unknown</span>
  <p class="card__text">Located two hours south of Sydney in the Southern Highland of New South Wales...</p>
  <div class="card__action-bar">
    <button class="card__button">SHARE</button>
    <button class="card__button show-more">LEARN MORE</button>
    <button class="card__button show-less hide">SHOW LESS</button>
  </div>
</div>
```